# How can I validate form with initial default data in Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

How can I validate form with initial default data?

```
anyForm.hasErrors() // always return  false.
```

I don't want to bind values manually. 
What I want to do:

```
anyForm.fill(anyModel)
```

Or

```
anyForm.bind(anyMethodToReturnMap(anyModel))
```

Where "anyModel" holds other models

Of course I could write my own method which returns Map from anyModel, just don't know if this method already exists in Play Framework.

Comment: You need to be more specific, maybe some sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind manually values, so that it can be validated then.

```
Map<String,String> anyData = new HashMap(); 
anyData.put("email", "bob@gmail.com"); 
anyData.put("password", "secret"); User user = 
userForm.bind(anyData); // then can validate userForm
```

Comment: Thx your solution works. However, this is not the solution I'm looking for. I don't want to bind values manually.

Comment: Validation is useful after binding values, either manually or from request.